# Boundary and initial conditions PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Good evening. My question concerns linear systems of PDE
How can I be sure I have provided the correct amount of initial and boundary conditions to find a unique solution? Do I have to give a quantity of boundary conditions equal to the degree of spatial derivatives and a quantity of initial conditions equal to the degree of temporal derivatives?

Comment: Your question is **too** general, in particular since it depends a lot on the type of equation. In case you are thinking of a specific type, please let us know what it is. Otherwise, there is no easy answer.